# Why RowLeave fires before CellLeave/CellValidating?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have an update statement under RowLeave event of my datagridview. Before I update it I need to validate the cell if there is an empty value. But whenever I moved the focus to another row, RowLeave is called first before CellLeave/CellValidating.

Is there another way of validating the cell when leaving a row?

Note: Leaving a cell in the same row is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well your app is acting as designed, see if you can listen to something in the nature of cellexitEditmode or cell validated (not entirely sure these are all there). Best practice is if the row represents and object that is bound say your row represents an order and your grid is bound to a collection of orders .  the cell will be a property in an order you can validate on property changed.